# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onDelete is not a function reactjs

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs

> The problem occurs when i'm trying to delete a to do list,onDelete is not a function.Full code is [here](https://github.com/sajinrules/react-todo) in the git.Thanks

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
    onDelete : function(key){
        console.log('remove here');
    },
    render: function() {
        var createItem = function(itemText,i) {
            return (
                <TodoListItem onDelete={this.remove} index={i} key=
                    {i}>{itemText}
                </TodoListItem>
            );
        };

        return(
            <ul id="staggered-test" className="collection with-
            header">
                <li className="collection-header">
                    <h4>todo list</h4>
                    {this.props.items.map(createItem)}
                </li>
            </ul>
      )
   }
});




var TodoListItem = React.createClass({
    remove : function(key){
        console.log('test:',key);
        console.log('that.props',this);
        this.props.onDelete();
    },
    render : function(){
        return(
            <li className="collection-item">
                <div>{this.props.children}
                    <a onClick=
                    {this.remove.bind(this,this.props.index)} href="#" className="secondary-content"><i className="material-icons">delete</i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change made is `{this.props.items.map(createItem)}` to `{this.props.items.map(createItem,this)}`

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
    remove : function(index){
        console.log('remove from here:',this.props.items);
        console.log('index:',index);
    },
    render: function() {
        var createItem = function(itemText,i) {
            return (
                <TodoListItem onDelete={this.remove.bind(this,i)} index={i} key={i}>{itemText}
                </TodoListItem>
            );
        };
        return(
            <ul id="staggered-test" className="collection 
                with-header">
                <li className="collection-header">
                    <h4>todo list</h4>
                    {this.props.items.map(createItem,this)}
                </li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
});
```

The is no need of the function `remove` in the class `TodoListItem`,because the parent has the function so that it can passed through `props`.

```
var TodoListItem = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return(
            <li className="collection-item">
                <div>{this.props.children}
                    <a onClick={this.props.onDelete} href="#" 
                    className="secondary-content">
                        <i className="material-icons">delete</i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the line

```
onDelete={this.remove}
```

This remove function is not defined. Is there anything your wnat to do in onDelete? If not, you can remove `this.props.onDelete();`

Comment: The state variable are defined in TodoList class, so access state variable to be deleted , I need to call TodoList class function. can you please check the github repo,Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Problem comes from this line

> onDelete={this.remove}

Change to

> onDelete={this.onDelete}